# change state of view of custom component in Atlassian UI kit (with Forge)

Tags: atlassian-forge, atlassian-ui

I would like to set the state of a checkbox to true in a custom component for Atlassian Jira when a button is clicked. I am using the UI kit with Forge.

So what do I have to write in the line // todo: check Checkbox "V2"?

```
import ForgeUI, { CustomField, CustomFieldEdit, render, Text, TextField, useProductContext, CheckboxGroup, Checkbox, Select, Option, Button } from "@forge/ui";


const View = () => {
  const { extensionContext: { fieldValue } } = useProductContext();

  return (
    <CustomField>
      <Text
        content={`Hello ${fieldValue || "world"}!`}
      />
    </CustomField>
  );
};

const Edit = () => {
  const onSubmit = values => {
      return values.text
  };
  
  const onClick = () => {
    // todo: check Checkbox "V2"
  };

  return (
    <CustomFieldEdit onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <CheckboxGroup label="Products" name="products">
        <Checkbox value="V1" label="V1" />
        <Checkbox value="V2" label="V2" />
        <Checkbox value="V3" label="V3" />
      </CheckboxGroup>
      <Button text="button" onClick={onClick} />
    </ CustomFieldEdit>
  );
}

export const runView = render(
  <View/>
);

export const runEdit = render(<Edit/>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that you've already found the solution, but for anyone else who comes across this same question here's the answer:

You don't actually need the button as part of the checkbox group, save is provided as part of `CustomFieldEdit` and so you just want to update the `onSubmit` function

```
const onSubmit = values => {
  const products = values.products.toString()
  console.log(products);
  return products;
};
```

However, I noticed if you're using the sample project created with **forge create**, you'll also need to hop on over to the `manifest.yml` and either remove the validation expression or update it to allow commas and numbers, or you'll just get a validation error.

```
validation:
  expression: value == null || !!value.match("^[A-Za-z]+$")
  errorMessage: The value must consist only of letters
```

Hope that helps! For faster answers it's probably worth heading over to the [Atlassian Developer Community](https://community.developer.atlassian.com/)